# Java - How to repair malformed JSON using the Regex?

Tags: java, json, regex, parsing

I have the following code which is parsing the content of the config file.

```
String DATA = "ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets\n" +
                        "driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1\n" +
                        "update_config=1\n" +
                        "device_name=P580_ROW\n" +
                        "manufacturer=LENOVO\n" +
                        "model_name=Lenovo \n" +
                        "model_number=Lenov\n" +
                        "serial_number=hjhjh7\n" +
                        "device_type=10-0050F204-5\n" +
                        "os_version=01020300\n" +
                        "config_methods=physical_display virtual_push_button\n" +
                        "p2p_no_group_iface=1\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "network={\n" +
                        "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
                        "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
                        "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                        "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                        "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                        "    priority=1\n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "network={\n" +
                        "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
                        "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
                        "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                        "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                        "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                        "    priority=1\n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "network={\n" +
                        "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
                        "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
                        "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                        "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                        "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                        "    priority=1\n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "network={\n" +
                        "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
                        "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
                        "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                        "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                        "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                        "    priority=1\n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "network={\n" +
                        "    ssid=\"SSID2\"\n" +
                        "    psk=\"test123456\"\n" +
                        "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
                        "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
                        "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
                        "    priority=19\n" +
                        "}";

                String rel="(\\{.*?\\})";   // Curly Braces 1
                List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rel, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(DATA);

                while (m.find()) {
                    String foundOccurence = m.group();
                    foundOccurence = foundOccurence.replace("=", ":");
                    foundOccurence = foundOccurence.replaceAll("\\s*([^:]+):(.*(\\n|$))","\"$1\":$2");
                    allMatches.add(foundOccurence);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < allMatches.size(); i++) {
                    String occurence = allMatches.get(i).toString();
                    Logger.d(occurence);
                }
```

And gives result like this:

[image]

But this is not valid JSON output.

I would like to have result like this.

```
{
    "ssid": "test1",
    "psk": "154695",
    "key_mgmt": "WPA-PSK",
    "sim_slot": "-1",
    "imsi": "none",
    "priority": "1"
}
```

How I should to update Regex to get valid JSON output?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Any reason not to just require that the config file is valid JSON first, and then use a normal JSON parser?

Comment: Also, I don't see where you're parsing a file. All I see is huge static string hard-coded in the code. You could also make that string valid JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few tweaks, your code can be altered to produce the output you described:

```
String rel = "\\{(.*?)\\}";   // Curly Braces 1
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rel, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(DATA);

while (m.find()) {
    String foundOccurence = m.group(1);
    foundOccurence = foundOccurence.replaceAll("=([^\"\\n]+)", "=\"$1\"");
    foundOccurence = foundOccurence.replaceAll("\\s*([\\w]+)=(\".*\")\\n", "  \"$1\": $2,\n");
    allMatches.add("{\n" + foundOccurence.substring(0, foundOccurence.length() - 2) + "\n},\n");
}

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String occurence : allMatches) {
    builder.append(occurence);
}
String result = builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 2);
```

The value of `result` becomes:

> ```
> {
>   "ssid": "test1",
>   "psk": "154695",
>   "key_mgmt": "WPA-PSK",
>   "sim_slot": "-1",
>   "imsi": "none",
>   "priority": "1"
> },
> {
>   "ssid": "test1",
>   "psk": "154695",
>   "key_mgmt": "WPA-PSK",
>   "sim_slot": "-1",
>   "imsi": "none",
>   "priority": "1"
> },
> {
>   "ssid": "test1",
>   "psk": "154695",
>   "key_mgmt": "WPA-PSK",
>   "sim_slot": "-1",
>   "imsi": "none",
>   "priority": "1"
> },
> {
>   "ssid": "test1",
>   "psk": "154695",
>   "key_mgmt": "WPA-PSK",
>   "sim_slot": "-1",
>   "imsi": "none",
>   "priority": "1"
> },
> {
>   "ssid": "SSID2",
>   "psk": "test123456",
>   "key_mgmt": "WPA-PSK",
>   "sim_slot": "-1",
>   "imsi": "none",
>   "priority": "19"
> }
> ```